# Edit many cell at the same time IGX GRID Angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, ignite-ui, ignite-ui-angular

I need to edit several cells at the same time that are in the same column. At the same time, so that the actual data change inside the cell is displayed. Is it possible to do this in igx grid Angular?

We can edit many cells in the same time!

Comment: Is this a question about Angular or AngularJS? It's confusing to include both tags.

Also, your last sentence seems to indicate you answered your own question.

Answer (score 0):

The igxGrid offers various ways for editing your data. While some may not directly meet your requirements, custom implementations can fulfill specific needs - You can enable column-type editing through a custom approach, by utilizing cell display templates and implementing two-way binding for cell values, you can facilitate direct editing and submission behavior.

For detailed guidance on implementing column templating, refer to the documentation provided in the [Column Templating section](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/grid/grid#cell-template)

Additionally, here you can [explore the editing capabilities](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/grid/batch-editing) offered by the Grids component.